# jquery find previous 12 months date from given date

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

Here , In jquery I am trying to find previous 12 month date from given date. but, the previous 12 months dates are wrong.

```
>     var now = new Date();
>     var months = new Array( "January", "February", "March", "April", "May","June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November",
> "December");
>     for(var i=0; i<=11;i++){
>     var past = now.setMonth(now.getMonth() -i);
>     console.log(months[now.getMonth()]+' '+now.getFullYear());
>     }
```

I am getting below output.

```
June 2016
May 2016
March 2016
December 2015
August 2015
March 2015
September 2014
February 2014
June 2013
September 2012
November 2011
December 2010
```

Comment: Did the answers below help?

Answer (score 4):

All you have to do is change:

```
now.getMonth() - i
```

To this

```
now.getMonth() - 1
```

That's it. Because you're modifying `now` in each iteration of your loop, just subtract *one* month instead of the loop variable.

See working example here: http://jsbin.com/nibizaqayu/edit?js,console

---

Also note that your `past` variable is doing nothing at this point, so your loop can look like this:

```
for(var i=0; i<=11;i++){
   now.setMonth(now.getMonth() - 1);
   console.log(months[now.getMonth()]+' '+now.getFullYear());
}
```

---

Another option would be to create a new `Date` instance as the other answers have shown, and it works equally well. However I personally find this to be simpler.

Answer (score 2):

When you call `setMonth` on `now` it manipulates that date, so next time you enter the loop, it's no longer the original value of `now`, and you are subtracting an incrementing counter.

Potential solution is to store new date object based off `now` in loop, then manipulate that, leaving `now` alone...

```
var now = new Date();
var months = new Array("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December");
for (var i = 0; i <= 11; i++) {
    var past = new Date(now); // @talemyn ;)
    past.setMonth(now.getMonth() - i);
    console.log(months[past.getMonth()] + ' ' + past.getFullYear());
}
```

... or you could set the value of `now` in increments of `1` instead of `i`...

```
var now = new Date();
var months = new Array("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December");
for (var i = 0; i <= 11; i++) {
    console.log(months[now.getMonth()] + ' ' + now.getFullYear());
    var past = now.setMonth(now.getMonth() - 1);
}
```

Comment: Almost identical to the solution that I was going to post, other than the fact that I used `var past = new Date(now);` on the (very) off chance that the difference in time between creating `now` and `past` resulted in different months.